# How does Google Analytics/Mixpanel/etc. determine the event timestamp when the clock is wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, mixpanel, localytics

In many devices (desktop and mobile) the clock is wrong, hence when try to determine an event time according to the client clock, that is results to inaccurate. Analytics services such as Google Analytics and Mixpanel recommend to use server timestamp to avoid that inaccuracy.
In case that the client clock is must (not server clock), what is the solution for that case?
For instance, in mobile SDK, a solution might be to execute an API call to time server and ignore the clock on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the analytics provider uses the timestamp from when the tracking request from the client was made. For example from the [Mixpanel documentation](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/http):

> If [the date] property is not included in your request, Mixpanel will use the time the event arrives at the server.

Offline use is more problematic, see [this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618719/how-does-google-analytics-for-android-handle-offline-app-usage) - by default Google Analytics will still use the timestamp when the tracking event was received.

That questions also mentions a queue time parameter to record events that occurred in the past. The value is relative and indicates how many milliseconds in the past the event occurred. That means it doesn't matter whether the client time is wrong, as long as the it advances at the correct speed.

That leaves the issue of people changing their clocks between when an event occurred and when it is tracked. This is probably rare enough to not be much of an issue in practice. Google Analytics' queue parameter is also ignored if it's too far in the past, and presumably if it's in the future.